# Dynamics CRM Fetch XML Return Customer Record

Tags: xml, crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I'm creating a custom report for Dynamics CRM 2011 using BIDS.
For a quote I have the potential customer type `customerEntityName` which returns either contact or account.
How do I link this to the correct customer entity to pull address details etc. into the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this; since it will only either be tied to an Account or a Contact, only one set of data will return values.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
   <entity name="quote">
    <attribute name="name"/> <attribute name="statecode"/> <attribute name="totalamount"/> <attribute name="customerid"/> <attribute name="quoteid"/> <order descending="false" attribute="name"/> -<link-entity name="account" alias="a_ce7d47f5258c4f20a6778ef6c718fa3b" link-type="outer" visible="false" to="customerid" from="accountid">
      <attribute name="address1_line1"/>
    </link-entity> -<link-entity name="contact" alias="quotecustomeridcontactcontactid" link-type="outer" visible="false" to="customerid" from="contactid">
      <attribute name="address1_line1"/>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```